# label positioning in forms (using div)

Tags: css, forms, html, input

Newbie Coder here. I'm trying to build a simple form (first, last, email, country), and I have labels corresponding to each. Positioning wise, I want to have the labels ABOVE each input. However, what I'm having some issues with is putting the first and last inputs next to each other (positioned horizontally) while keeping the labels above.

```
<div id="firstlast" class="grid_8">
     <label for="first">First Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
     <label for="last">Last Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="last" id="last"><br>
  </div>
```

and the CSS

```
.firstlast div {
   float: left;
   clear: none;
   display:inline;
}
```

I can use a linebreak to position the first over the input, but the linebreak still **applies** to the second label and form.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to nest them in their own containers and float them. Or just do the one.

```
<div id="firstlast" class="grid_8">
  <div style="float:left;">
      <label for="first">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
  </div>

  <label for="last">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="last" id="last"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
<form name="" method="post">
       <div style="float:left;margin-right:20px;">
            <label for="first">First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="first" id="first">

        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <label for="last">Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="last" id="last">
        </div>

        <label for="subject">Subject</label>
        <input id="subject" type="text" value="" name="subject">

        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <input id="message" type="text" value="" name="message">

    </form>
```

And CSS:

```
input, label {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define `.firstlast` **Class** in css .   But you **used** `ID` in your **html code** why

### -----------------------------------------------------

Now you can try this 
Define your `label` `display block` in css as like this

```
label{
    display:block;
    magin-top:20px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cwmjE/)

============================
Try Second Method is this

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="firstlast">
    <div  class="grid_8">
    <div class="control-group"> 
    <label for="first">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
        </div>  <div class="control-group">
      <label for="last">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="last" id="last">
        </div>
</div>
         <div  class="grid_8">
    <div class="control-group"> 
    <label for="first">email</label>
      <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
        </div>  <div class="control-group">
      <label for="last">country</label>
      <input type="text" name="last" id="last">
        </div>
</div>
        </div>
```

**Css**

```
.grid_8{overflow:hidden;margin-top:20px;}
.control-group{
  float:left;
    width:50%;
}
.control-group label{

   display:block;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cwmjE/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you want first label and input field in horizontal and for rest you want label text just above the input field.

Here is the css code should like..

```
input[type="text"]{
  padding:10px;
}

label{vertical-align:top; 
padding:10px 0;
  display:block;
}

#firstlast {
width:250px;
}
label:first-child, input:first-child{  display:inline; padding:0 5px 0 0;}
```

HTML should like this.

```
<div id="firstlast" class="grid_8">
      <label for="first">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first" id="first">
      <label for="last">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="last" id="last">
  <label for="email">e-mail</label>
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
```

And here is the working Demo.
http://jsbin.com/nugucelu/1/edit